# Java GUI, creating piano keys using JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, glasspane

I'm trying to create a simple piano application using Java, and I'm stuck at creating the keys.

[image: Awesome]

So what I have is a bunch of (Black) JButtons on top of (White) JButtons, but whenever I click the white buttons, it covers the black buttons.

So my question is; how do I implement this so the black JButtons would stay on top of the white ones.

Comment: How are you positioning the `JButton`s in the first place?  Possibly, JLayeredPane is the way to go for you.

Comment: *"how do I implement this so the black JButtons would stay on top of the white ones."*  What is your current code?  Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're laying out your buttons in the first place.  I suggest you use `JLayeredPane` for the layout.  With it, you specify z-index of each component - and it takes care of the rest.  Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html#depth